Why type inference fails

I use ItemMap to map each type to its corresponding item.

 type ItemMap = {
  write: string[];
  see: string[];
  find: DataLibraryType[];
  read: UploadFile[];
};


The generic parameter K of SearchListProps is used to realize that different currentWay corresponds to different list types.

interface SearchListProps<K extends WaysType> {
 currentWay: K;
 list: ItemMap[K];
 onClick: (val: ItemMap[K][number]) => void;
 onRemove?: () => void;
}

type WaysType = 'write' | 'read' | 'see' | 'find'

I want the list to be able to infer different types based on the value of currentWay
But ts error
The parameter “index” implicitly has type “any”, but better types can be inferred from usage. ts(7044)
and When currentWay = 'read' , the list type error
error msg : Attribute “name” does not exist on type “string | DataLibraryType | UploadFile”  Attribute “name” does not exist on type “string”.
const SearchList = <K extends WaysType>(props: SearchListProps<K>) => {
  const { currentWay, list, onClick, onRemove } = props
  switch (currentWay) {
    case 'write':
    case 'see':
    case 'find':
      return <div>
        {
          list.map((r, index) => {
            const itemName = currentWay === 'find' ? r?.name : r
            return <div key={index}>{itemName}</div>
          })
        }
      </div>
    case 'read':
      const currentFile = list?.[0]
// Attribute “name” does not exist on type “string | DataLibraryType | UploadFile<any>”  Attribute “name” does not exist on type “string”.
      const fileType = getFileExtension(currentFile?.name) || 'file'
      if (!currentFile) {
        return <></>
      }
      return <div>{currentFile?.desc}</div>
    default:
      return <></>
  }
}

I want the list to be able to infer different types based on the value of currentWay
  switch (currentWay) {
    case 'write':
    case 'see':
    case 'find':
      return <div>
        {
          list.map((r, index) => {
            const itemName = currentWay === 'find' ? r?.name : r
            return <div key={index}>{itemName}</div>
          })
        }
      </div>
    case 'read':
        // list type is UploadFile[] no error
    return <div>... </div>
    


Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now you've got types like DataLibraryType and UploadFile and crucially getFileExtension, which have not been provided or defined. So when I look at this I get a lot of errors, but not the one you're asking about.

The problem here is that typescript can't narrow down your K parameter on its own. If you want to know why, please refer to narrowing guide, quite a read actually.
So you have to help typescript to narrow it down.
First, please read about discriminated unions here
The idea behind this union is that if you have a literal type field, like yours WaysType, you can use unions to define better typing instead of generic K type.
type WaysType = 'write' | 'read' | 'see' | 'find';

interface BaseProps {
  onRemove?: () => void;
}

interface WriteOrSeeProps extends BaseProps {
  currentWay: 'write' | 'see';
  list: string[];
  onClick: (val: string) => void;
}

interface FindProps extends BaseProps {
  currentWay: 'find';
  list: DataLibraryType[];
  onClick: (val: DataLibraryType) => void;
}

interface ReadProps extends BaseProps {
  currentWay: 'read';
  list: UploadFile[];
  onClick: (val: UploadFile) => void;
}

type SearchListProps = WriteOrSeeProps | FindProps | ReadProps;

Having union interfaces helps Typescript to define type inference based on the switch case control flow you implemented.
Here is a link to typescript playground with your current code problem playground
Here is a link to typescript playground to illustrate how unions are not throwing any errors solution playground
